# How to listen to new User registered event in Accounts using Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How do I hook a function when a new `User` is registered using the package [meteor-useraccounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core)?

I can't see any event listeners in the docs, thanks!

Comment: On the server or the client?

Comment: @Joaquin http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: thanks! that was it :)